# Clone <tr> from a form and append to another form - but losing links(events)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmpp, cisco

I am modifying a third party built  web client messaging API to increase the number of servers I can search on for chat rooms. THe API is  built to search on one server node. The server response is in form of FORM (without methods to get fields from) and publishes it to browser via callback.

The result will be a list of search rooms, which when selected will trigger and event and lets the user join the chat room.

I have modified the code so that it throws the search request multiple times, and gets multiple response FORMS that displays into multiple div's.

I have cloned /.clone(true)/ the rows and successfully appended them to the last form, displaying perfectly (thanks to the other posts here:) BUT user will only be able to select the list from the last FORM response, and the other list will only appear as texts.

Is there a way to clone the links as well? I am very new to web programming and I am thinking that the links are only active when in a certain instance, (which when the form was received - and instance will be replaced when another form is received) but I cannot be very sure of this.

This is the function wherein the last form will be received and the saved rows will be appended.

```
 _01handleConfigSubmit: function (form, error) {
            if (form) {
                var formView = new jabberwerx.ui.XDataFormView(form);                
                var that = this;

               formView.event("xdataItemSelected").bind(function(evt) {

                    that.jq.find(".muc_search_button_join").removeAttr("disabled");

                    var resultTable = that.jq.find(".muc_search_results table.result_table");
                    resultTable.find("tr.selected").removeClass("selected");

                    that._selectedItem = evt.data.selected;
                    resultTable.find("tr#"+evt.data.selected._guid).addClass("selected");
                });


                var searchResultsDiv = jabberwerx.$(".muc_search_results", this.jq);
                searchResultsDiv.empty();
                this.update();
                var dim = {
                    width: searchResultsDiv.width(),
                    height: searchResultsDiv.height()
                };
                formView.render().appendTo(searchResultsDiv);
                formView.dimensions(dim);

                $("table.result_table tbody").append($trs);     

            } else {
                this._showError(error);
            }
        },
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where in this function is the cloning happening?

Comment: I suspect the problem is using `formView.render()` to clone the element. That just gets the HTML, losing any event handlers. You need a method that returns the actual DOM element, then you can use jQuery's `.clone(true)` to clone it along with event handlers.

Comment: Hey Banmar, .clone(true) did the trick!!! Thank you very much.

I did the cloning on another function, saving the object as a global variable. I am still using .render(). Thanks you very much!